# Rails - Building Conditions for Use in a Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I usually like to build a conditions hash like this below:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:color] = "black"
conditions[:doors] = 4
conditions[:type] = "sedan"

Cars.find(:all, :conditions=>conditions)
```

But how would I add a date range into this for something like:

```
year >= '2011-01-01' and year < '2011-02-01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Rails 2.3.x and `year` is a date column.

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:color] = "black"
conditions[:doors] = 4
conditions[:type] = "sedan"
# create a date range
conditions[:year] = (Date.parse("2011-01-01")...Date.parse("2011-02-01"))

Car.all(:conditions => conditions)
```

If you want to do even more complex queries in 2.3.x use the [AR Extensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions/tree/master/ar-extensions/) gem. 
Read [this](http://www.continuousthinking.com/2007/3/14/activerecord-extensions-0-5-0-released) article for more details.

Comment: To match the condition "year >= '2011-01-01' and year < '2011-02-01'", use three dots in your Range: Date.parse("2011-01-01")...Date.parse("2011-02-01")

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I didn't notice the `>=` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a up query through relations.  The query will not be executed until it needs to be evaluated.  This is nice for searches where some parameters are optional.

```
@cars = Cars.where(:color => "black")
@cars = @cars.where(:doors => 4)
@cars = @cars.where("year >= '2011-01-01'")
@cars = @cars.where("year <= '2011-02-01'")
```

Or you could just merge all that together into one:

```
Cars.where(["color=? AND doors=? AND year >= ? AND year <= ?", "black", 4, "2011-01-01", "2011-02-01"]
```

UPDATE:
For Rails < 3

```
@cars = Cars.scoped(:conditions => {:color => "black"})
@cars = @cars.scoped(:conditions => {:doors => 4})
@cars = @cars.scoped(:conditions => "year >= '2011-01-01'")
@cars = @cars.scoped(:conditions => "year <= '2011-02-01'")
```

OR

```
Cars.all(:conditions => ["color=? AND doors=? AND year >= ? AND year <= ?", "black", 4, "2011-01-01", "2011-02-01"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Rails 3, why not use AREL?

```
Cars.where(:color => "black").
     where(:doors => 4).
     where(:type => "sedan").
     where("year >= '2011-01-01'").
     where("year < '2011-02-01'")
```

Btw, don't use :type as a field name. Rails uses this for STI.

On Rails 2.3, I'd just build up `conditions` as a String instead.